# Using JS variable as the property of HTML input Form

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have a form which have two field "optin" and "Qty".The quantity field of the form accept the number.The minimum number which can be entered in this field(QTY) depends upon the the value of the Option field i.e. If the option fiels value is red then the minimum value propert of the Qty field should be 5 and if it is 'Red' then the minimum property of the Qty field should be 10. I am doing it by the given code but its not working.

```
<td><input type="text" name="option" onkeydown="random()" class="form-control"  >

<script>
            function random()
            {
                
                var a=document.getElementById('option').value;
                if(a==="red")
                {
                    var minimum = '5';
                }
                else if(a==="green")
                {
                    var minimum= '10';
                }
                    
            }
       </script>
       <input type="NUMBER" name="qty"  class="form-control" min=<?php var minimum ?>  ></td>
```

Comment: php is a server side language. So, you can interact with it throught direct request or an ajax call. That being said its better to continue your idea through javascript because it works in a client side

Comment: @Amir Can you help me out with solution plz because I am not aware about Ajax

Comment: Then don't over complicate things the problem you're facing could be solved through javascript just add event lisetener for value change. Do you want me to help in this direction?

Comment: @Amir Plz help   me in that direction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!-- This is the code you provided -->
<td><input type="text" name="option" onkeydown="random()" class="form-control"  >

<script>
            function random()
            {
                
                var a=document.getElementById('option').value;
                if(a==="red")
                {
                    var minimum = '5';
                }
                else if(a==="green")
                {
                    var minimum= '10';
                }
                    
            }
       </script>
       <input type="NUMBER" name="qty"  class="form-control" min=<?php var minimum ?>  ></td>
```

Let's see...
First of all lets change your if else case with a switch:

```js
switch(a){
    case "red":
        var minimum = 5;
        break;
    case "green":
        var minimum = 10;
        break;
}
```

Now I will remove the php tag and add a line to change the min value of the input.

```html
<td><input type="text" id="option" onkeydown="random()" class="form-control"  />

<script>
            function random()
            {
                var a=document.getElementById('option').value;
                switch(a){
                    case "red":
                        var minimum = 5;
                        break;
                    case "green":
                        var minimum = 10;
                        break;
                }
                document.getElementById("input").setAttribute("min", minimum)//this line adds an attribute or sets it to a given value
            }
       </script>
       <input type="NUMBER" id="input"  class="form-control" /></td>
```

Now let's see this code in action!
Run the following snippet.

```html
<td><input type="text" id="option" onchange="random()" class="form-control"  />

<script>
            function random()
            {
                var a=document.getElementById('option').value;
                switch(a){
                    case "red":
                        var minimum = 5;
                        break;
                    case "green":
                        var minimum = 10;
                        break;
                }
                document.getElementById("input").setAttribute("min", minimum)//this line adds an attribute or sets it to a given value
            }
       </script>
       <input type="NUMBER" id="input"  class="form-control" /></td>
```

And done! Also, I changed the `onkeydown` to `onchange`.

Comment: Can i use array type element option[ ], input[ ] in this

Comment: You can if you make an array called option or input and then you can take a value from the array and then do the same thing!

Comment: Please mark the answer accepted if it helped that will not only help others know what is the correct answer and also help me know you got it. Thank you!

Comment: But it is not working for array.actually there are multiple input for option and input field in second field the input minimum value remains same for first .

Comment: for array it is easy see. First get the input from all inputs. Just use `document.getElementById("<your id here").value` and then form an array from all the values. After that use a forEach loop to go through the array and run a function or else take the index of one element and say `arr[<index of the element>]` and then run the function on that. Simple! Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

1. Added more rows in case there are many rows with the same fields.
2. Secondly, I have added an event listener instead of direct function
   call but you can do either.
3. Extracting into calculatingMinimunQuantity for easier readibility
   and calling setAttribute (min) there.

```js
var options = document.querySelectorAll(".option");
options.forEach(function(option) {
  option.addEventListener("change", function() {
    calculatingMinimunQuantity(option);
  });
});

function calculatingMinimunQuantity(option) {
  var minimum = 0;
  var value = option.value;
  if (value === "red") {
    minimum = "5";
  } else if (value === "green") {
    minimum = "10";
  }
  //   getting the quantity input field
  option.nextElementSibling.setAttribute("min", minimum);
}
```

```html
<td>
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="option form-control" placeholder="option" name="option" />
    <input type="NUMBER" class="form-control" name="qty" placeholder="quantity" />
  </div>
</td>

<td>
  <div>
    <input type="text" class="option form-control" placeholder="option" name="option" />
    <input type="NUMBER" class="form-control" name="qty" placeholder="quantity" />
  </div>
</td>
```